# Objects added as subview to scrollview are not showing up

Tags: iphone, sdk, for-loop, while-loop, scrollview

I am trying to add elements to a scroll view using this code:

```
int missionCount;
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *missionsDict = [responseString JSONValue];
/*NSArray *luckyNumbers = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];*/
NSLog(@"user Info array is: %@", missionsDict);
//    NSDictionary *array = [luckyNumbers1 objectForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *missionsData;
missionsData = [missionsDict objectForKey:@"data"];
NSLog(@"missionsData is: %@", missionsData);
NSEnumerator *inner = [missionsData objectEnumerator];
missionsScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 1005);

id value;
int badgeY1;
int badgeY2;
int badgeY3;
badgeY1 = 146;
badgeY2 = 188;
badgeY3 = 188;
while((value = [inner nextObject])) {
    NSLog(@"value is: %@", value);
    NSLog(@"progress is: %@", [value objectForKey:@"progress"]);
    NSLog(@"user Info array is: %@", missionsDict);
    NSLog(@"name is: %@",[value objectForKey:@"reward_definitions"]);
    NSLog(@"missionsData is: %@", missionsData);
    NSDictionary *moreData;
    moreData = [value objectForKey:@"reward_definitions"];
    NSEnumerator *inner2 = [moreData objectEnumerator];
    id value2;
    int badgeX;
    int badgeCount;
    badgeX = 0;
    badgeCount = 0;
    while((value2 = [inner2 nextObject])) {
        UIProgressView *progressView;
        progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323, badgeY1, 372, 9)];
        float progressValue;
        progressValue = ([[[value objectForKey:@"progress"] objectForKey:@"earned"] floatValue] / [[[value objectForKey:@"progress"] objectForKey:@"possible"] floatValue]);
        NSLog(@"progressValue is: %f", progressValue);
        [progressView setProgress:progressValue];
        [missionsScroll addSubview:progressView];
        UILabel *missionName;
        missionName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(66, badgeY1, 227, 21)];
        missionName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        missionName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        missionName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:23.0];
        missionName.text = [value objectForKey:@"name"];
        [missionsScroll addSubview:missionName];

        UILabel *requirementsLabel;
        requirementsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(66, badgeY2+25, 227, 21)];
        requirementsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        requirementsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        requirementsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:19];
        requirementsLabel.text = @"To complete you need:";
        [missionsScroll addSubview:requirementsLabel];

        NSLog(@"Image URL is: %@", [value2 objectForKey:@"image_url"]);
        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [value2 objectForKey:@"image_url"]]];            
        NSData *urlData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData1];
        UIImageView *badge = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
        [badge setFrame:CGRectMake(badgeX, badgeY2+70, 70, 70)];               
        [missionsScroll addSubview:badge];
        [badge release];
        badgeCount = badgeCount+1;
        NSLog(@"badgeCount is: %i", badgeCount);
        if (badgeCount == 4) {
            NSLog(@"Badge Count = 4");
            badgeY2 = badgeY2 +70;
            badgeX = 0;
            badgeCount = 0;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Badge Count ≠ 4");
            badgeX = badgeX +75;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"1st While loop done");

    // NSLog(@"reward_definitions is: %@", [missionsData objectForKey:@"id"]);
    //       NSLog(@"Image URL is: %@", [[value objectForKey:@"reward_definitions"] objectForKey:@"image_url"]);
    //if ( [array isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
    badgeY1 = badgeY1 +200;

    badgeY2 = badgeY2 +200;

    badgeY3 = badgeY3 +200;
    missionCount = missionCount+1; 
}
NSLog(@"While loops done");

for (int a; missionCount > 4; a = a+1) {
    missionsScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(776, missionsScroll.contentSize.height+200);
}
```

Nothing is showing up in the scroll view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious what is happening, but first things to check are where the views are valid (not nil) and that this code is running on the main thread.

Put these in and post the results.

```
   NSLog(@"missionsScroll: %@", (missionsScroll==nil)?@"NIL":@"OK");
   NSLog(@"progressView: %@", (progressView==nil)?@"NIL":@"OK");
   NSLog(@"missionName: %@", (missionName==nil)?@"NIL":@"OK");
   NSLog(@"mainThread: %@", ([NSThread isMainThread])?@"OK":@"Background Thread");
```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to verify the frames of the views are within the superview.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite convoluted and very difficult to read. Perhaps you could check if your complicated coordinates calculations work as expected, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"Frame of badge %@", NSStringFromCGRect(badge.frame));
```

Answer (score 1):

How many times are your while loops iterating? The outer loop increases the y-position of your labels. But the labels will only be displayed at the end of the run loop / start of the next run loop. If you exit this method with the labels with a high y-value then you'll not see them. (It doesn't matter how many times you change the y-value while you're running this code. The display will only update when it's all done.)

** Correction ** You seem to be adding new views each time around your while loop. So in fact I'd expect you to have multiple copies of the subviews appearing when they finally get displayed.

(There's a lot of code to wade through here. If my answer is way off, you might get better answers, but trimming back some of the code and isolating the issue.)